# C# Shared Classlib -> display progress to webforms and/or console App

Tags: c#, asp.net, console

Not sure if the title covers the question well, but here it comes.

I have a project with:

- A website: webforms (Aps.net 4,c#) where the user can upload files, interact with them and manually trigger some batch processing
- A classlib with all the business logic for the processing
- An app that runs on a machine at the customers location and is scheduled to upload files by SFTP to our server.
- A console app that is scheduled on the server and does the batch processing for the files that are uploaded by SFTP.

'heavy use customers' use the SFTP app, the others use the website.

The console app and the website both use the same classlib.

What mechanism can I use to send logging/progress information to the website or the console app without implementing two classlibs? I do not want the classlib to be aware that it is called by the console app or the website. For example they also share the same settings. etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events.

You could add events to the classes that perform the actual business logic in your shared lib.  When something happens that requires feedback, you can raise that event in the class.

The consuming application (either the console app or the web-app) can subscribe to  those events, and take the appropriate action that is specific to their platform.

A very simplyfied example:

```
public class SomeLogicClass
{
   public event EventHandler SomethingDone;

   protected virtual void OnSomethingDone()
   {
      if( SomethingDone != null )
      {
           SomethingDone(this, EventArgs.Empty);
      }
   }

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       // Do some work.
       OnSomethingDone();
   }
}
```

In your console-app you can do this, for instance:

```
var x = new SomeLogicClass();
x.SomethingDone += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine ("Work done.");
x.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Move the work done by the shared lib in its own thread and you have the best of both the background worker solution and the events solution without binding your lib to a backgroundworker object. But beware of the added complexity when using threads!

Comment: Offcourse, the businesslogic can be executed on another thread.  However, this brings some extra work since you want to make sure that the eventhandler executes on the correct context. :)

Comment: So you want a progress report event handler to run in the same thread then? So if, like in this case that progress report is about sending data over http, you want to block the work in the meantime? The criteria here is to report progress/log during execution, not after.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying ...  read my post and comments.  The answer the question, on how to make sure the UI is loosely coupled from the core, is by using events.  The question was not how to make it responsive.  Indeed, if you want to have it responsive, you'll have to make use of threading, as said in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Events idea solves nothing as it will block the main thread and e.g. not be useful for reporting progress in a responsive UI.

Use BackgroundWorker:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += ProgressComplete;
        worker.DoWork += DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    { 
        //Runs on seperate thread
        //Do stuff
        //(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress... reports back to main thread
        //Do other stuff
    }

    private static void ProgressComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Executed on main thread
        Console.Out.WriteLine("All Done");
    }

    private static void ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Can be used to asynchronously send status updates or update UI elements on the main thread
        Console.Out.WriteLine("{0:P} done", e.ProgressPercentage/100.0);
    }
```

Comment: Let me mention that a backgroundworker uses events as well to communicate back to the caller.  The BackGroundWorker is just some implementation that you can use *inside* the BL-classes to make sure that your logic executes on another thread (if you want to), but the BackgroundWorker isn't the only solution to do this.

Comment: That wasn't my point, the point is that events alone don't solve this issue. Using a BackgroundWorker or Thread/Task to do some job on a separate thread and then having another thread doing the reporting. It would not make any sense to block a job while a progress reporting function sends data through a tcp pipe for example. Events are merely a way of communicating